# Segmentation fault: 11 Assembly OSX

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly, x86

Hi I'm still new to the Assembly language using gcc compiler, right now I'm working on functions.
My program asks the user for 4 `int` values, store those values in register `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` and `edx`, then calls a function to divide (`ebx/eax`). I store the value of "d" after the division because as I understand `idiv` uses `edx` to store the residue. It then subtracts (`eax-ecx`) and multiply (`eax*edx`), then returns the value inside of register `eax`. For some reason I get a segmentation fault: 11.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a, b, c, d;

int main (void)
{
    printf("Dame a: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Dame b: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("Dame c: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    printf("Dame d: ");
    scanf("%d", &d);

    __asm(    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
              "xor eax, eax;"
              "mov eax, dword ptr [_a];" 
              "xor ebx, ebx;"
              "mov ebx, dword ptr [_b];"
              "xor ecx, ecx;"
              "mov ecx, dword ptr [_c];"
              "Call fun1;"
              "mov dword ptr [_a], eax;"


              "fun1:  xor edx, edx;"
              "idiv ebx;"
              "sub eax, ecx;"
              "mov edx, dword ptr [_d];"
              "imul eax, edx;"
              "ret;"

              ".att_syntax");

    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Is it something to do with some pointer error?

Comment: There is no function called from the C code. This looks like wrongly integrated assembler code. How do you think this executes? You don't pass C variables correctly to the assembler code, have no clobbers listed, etc. Please read how inline-assembler has to be used.

Comment: Also, it's bad idea to switch syntax in inline asm. Use `gcc -masm=intel` if you want intel syntax asm. PS: your execution falls through into `fun1` and then the `ret` when hit the 2nd time will exit from `main` (if you are lucky, otherwise it will crash).

Comment: Hi Jester thanks for the answer, I know is bad practice to switch the syntax in inline asm, for some reason if I don't do that i get 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode error.

Comment: I'm surprised that compiles even with intel syntax. If you are truly compiling for 64-bit, on top of every other comment I'd probably use RIP addressing. As an example I'd code `dword ptr [_a]` as `[rip+_a]`. In AT&T syntax that would be `_a(%rip)`

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the other errors pointed out in comments, you have a significant issue here:

```
         "mov ecx, dword ptr [_c];"
          "Call fun1;"
          "mov dword ptr [_a], eax;"


          "fun1:  xor edx, edx;"
          "idiv ebx;"
          "sub eax, ecx;"
          "mov edx, dword ptr [_d];"
          "imul eax, edx;"
          "ret;"
```

Consider the program flow. Your C code falls into this assembly code. The assembly code calls an internal function of its own (not a problem), which then returns to the instruction before the call... Still no problem. A value is moved into EAX... and you then fall through your function to a return.  This is horribly bad.

By falling through to that `ret` you are bypassing the entire C function epilog. This means that the stack is not properly cleaned up, nor is the stack from restored. This will almost certainly lead to a crash.